# eclipse luna doesnt support glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-luna

I downloaded `eclipse-jee-luna-SR1-x86_64`

*I went to servers view* -> *right clicked and add new server* -> *download additional server adapters* -> *there is nothing for glassfish*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install one from Marketplace:http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-luna

Comment: Be careful of an annoying bug. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786155/glassfish-4-1-deploy-is-failing-on-eclipse-luna-with-jdk-8/28084272#28084272